# DistributionNotFound when trying to run console script in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

I created a virtualenv with python2.7 a few weeks ago and got this project running fine. It uses setuptools and has a few console scripts defined.

Now today I installed python3 and pip3, which I didn't think would conflict with this project but I'm running into this error when I try to run the same console script.

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: myproject==1.0.0.0-local

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/dev/myproject/venv-myproject/bin/run_queue_worker_manager", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/me/dev/project/venv-myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2720, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/Users/me/dev/project/venv-myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

Comment: Did you activate your new environment properly? Note that your error suggests that the script of your `python2.7` environment was called.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the hint cel, I ran `python setup.py develop` again and the problem was resolved.  Now is this something I will need to do regularly? I read [a brief intro to packaging python](http://www.ewencp.org/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-packaging-python/) and it explains that this command links the current directory into my virtualenv, but I can't see why this would stop working since I never explicitly ran `python setup.py develop --uninstall`